# what is the case when a programe can run as normal but not in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb

I have a programe, which is so simple. The code as below.
I compiled it with

```
gcc -g -Wall -I../software/libxml2-2.9.0/include/  
       -lxml2 -L/usr/lib test.c -o test
```

I can absolutely run it with "./test", but when I run it with "gdb test" and then print "run" it will receive signal SIGSEGV. So I want to know what happened?

```
#include <libxml/xmlreader.h> 
int main( void )
{
   const char *file = "/usr/share/mime/application/javascript.xml";
   xmlNewTextReaderFilename( file );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: SIGSEGV is segmentation fault.  The debugger is probably catching it before it is actually ran whereas when you run the program itself it will not seg fault until it reaches that point.

Comment: What is the input type for `xmlNewTextReaderFilename`?  I would make sure you are sending the correct type. Note: a `const char *` is not the same as `char *`.

Comment: let it segfault, then type `bt` to see the call stack

Comment: What is the result of running `where` after the SIGSEGV?

Comment: @Josh: The first actually relevant links on Google seem to indicate it wants a `const char *`, so there is no reason for it to SIGSEGV. @wuwl: Is the sigsegv unhandled, or is it handled by libxml's code? If the latter, then for all we know, this could be normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are debugging using `gdb test` you may actually be debugging `/bin/test` rather that your own program.  If the backtrace does not correspond to your expected program switch to `gdb ./test` (in a similar manner to how you are running the program as `./test`)

Comment: @djf : I really used bt to print the stack. And it shows coredump because of the second arg of function strncmp, it is a uninitialized point. But what i want to know is why this can happen in gdb but not in running normal.

Comment: @Medinoc: Both libxml and my code are not set any handler for SIGSEGV.